# Prolog movies.pl most co-stars

Tags: prolog

Given this database, http://swish.swi-prolog.org/example/movies.pl, I have to find the top 25 actors/actresses, with the most co-stars. I don't know how to check on all of them, in order to get their partners.

Co-star defined in prolog: `co_star(A1, A2)`, where `A1` (actor 1) is co-star with `A2` (actor 2).

```
co_star(A1,A2,N):-
    findall(M,actor(M,A1),L1),  %L1: movies, starring A1
    findall(M2,actor(M2,A2),L2), %L2: starring A2
    intersection(L1,L2,L),          %L: starring A1 and A2
    length(L,N),
    N>0.                              %if the list of the movies is more than 1,    they are co-stars.

top_25:-              %so, the actual problem
    findall(A1,actor(_M,A1),L1),  %L1: I think I should store all the actors
    findall(A2,actor(_M,A2),L2),  
    findall(N,co_star(F,_A2,N),L), %so I need this list "L" where all the number of co-stars are stored for all the actors(descending, only the top 25)
    write(L).
```

Comment: What have you tried so far (edit your post to add some code)? What errors are you getting? What's the output compared to what you want the output to be?

Comment: You know what your facts are. At least try to describe in words, *`A1` and `A2` are co-stars if.... (something in terms of the facts)*. From there, you can get to the Prolog. If you're not familiar with Prolog, try a tutorial or a good Prolog book.

Comment: You don't need `findall` for `co_star` at all. Remember: you're defining a rule that defines whether `A1` is a co-star with `A2`, not trying to collect all co-stars at that point.. Try not to think so imperatively. In prolog, if you say, `actor(Movie, Person, Role)` it's a query and Prolog will generate, one by one through backtracking, every solution for `Movie`, `Person`, and `Role`. And a co-star is an actor *on the same film*, which is a logical element you haven't captured. Finally, the `actor` facts require 3 arguments, not 2. And you'll need to take into account actresses.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Forgot to specify: in my case, there is no "role" argument, just Movie and Person.